# canvas.clipPath() not working even after disabling harware acceleration

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have drawn a circle filled with black color in the canvas and I have set the background color of the canvas to red.

I want only the circle which is black color to appear as my view but I get the red color as well.

I tried using canvas.clipPath() it dint work. I searched the net and found out we need to disable hardware acceleration to get it work. I tried that but it still dint work.

Tried disabling the Hardware Acceleration for particular view:

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

And also to whole application:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Dint work in both the cases.
Any ideas on how to make it work ?

[image]

Code:

And here I am clipping

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas = canvas;
    path.reset();
    left = 50;
    top = 50;
    right = getWidth()- 50;
    bottom = getHeight()-50;



    RectF rectf = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
    path.arcTo(rectf, startAngle, sweepAngle);
    path.lineTo(linex, liney);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    //canvas.restore();
}
```

Comment: please provide the code where you used the clipPath

Comment: @NirHartmann I have added the code in the  question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not what clip path is for. When you draw a path and then clip it - it means that the rest of the things you will draw on the canvas from that point will be masked by the path.
In your case you draw a red background before clipping the canvas - so it went all over the canvas, then you clipped it but draw only inside the path, so the clipping was useless.

you can get what you need that in that code:

```
// Do not set any background to the view before
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas = canvas;
    path.reset();
    left = 50;
    top = 50;
    right = getWidth()- 50;
    bottom = getHeight()-50;



    RectF rectf = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
    path.arcTo(rectf, startAngle, sweepAngle);
    path.lineTo(linex, liney);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), Red Paint in here);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    //canvas.restore();
}
```

That way you draw the background after pathClip

You will not see any red color because you draw all over the path right after it, if I am guessing right - you want to be able to draw a part of a circle in one color and the rest in other - you can achieve it if your path that you will clip will be the full circle and the path that you draw will be the part that you want to draw

Comment: okay I will explain a bit more. I think u understood my question wrong. In my image above I have drawn a circle in a canvas. The circle is filled with black color and the rest area is filled with red color (red color - empty space in canvas). I will be adding multiple circles in my activity. I dont want that extra space to be present in my activity

Comment: I will be replacing the extra red color (Color.RED) with Color.TRANSPARENT- Just to show the extra space being generated I have put the red color

Comment: I hope u understood my problem now?

Comment: So basically I just want to clip the black circle from my canvas and remove those extra space (i.e remove entire region with red color)

Comment: The extra spacing is the 50px that you add to the left and top

Comment: Yes and I need that i will be drawing different type of images and I dont want to change the canvas size

Comment: So I really dont understand the problem - if you make your background transparent you will get what you want

Comment: I will be having onTouch listener on each image added to my activity. And the images are kept very close to each other, And because of the extra spaces the touch events are not being called correctly

Comment: Some times the image which I am drawing on the canvas will be small. At that time the extra space will be more and it cause a lot more prob in handling touch events cause the extra space will not be visible to user, if the user touches the extra space which is invisible the touch event gets fired.

Comment: So thats y I want my view to be in the shape of wat is being drawn and not contain any extra space

Comment: ok, so you can add onTouchEvent to your views, check if the event.getX() and event.getY() are in your path, if so return super.onTouchEvent(event), or do whatever you do there, and if not, return false - so the touch will go on the then next view below it

Comment: maybe this will help you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse